# How do I create logged-in only routes for a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a MERN stack Facebook clone where if the user is not logged in, they will be taken to a landing page with signup/login forms. If the user is logged in, they will be taken to the main app with `"/"`, `"/messages"`, `"/profile"`, and `"/users/:userID"` routes.

Originally I had them all within `app.js`, with a `isLoggedIn` function that returns a boolean. I tried to do the following, but now it can't find any of my logged-in only routes except for `"/"`. Everything works as it should on `"/"` and `"/welcome"`, and the re-direction works both ways in `app.js`.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/app/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Feed from '../feed/Feed';
import HomePage from '../../pages/HomePage';
import {
  useNavigate,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../utilities/LoggedInCheck';
import LandingPage from '../../pages/LandingPage';
import AuthenticatedRoutes from './AuthenticatedRoutes';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* ====== AUTHENTICATION ONLY - Search, Messages, Friends, Notifications : ======== */}
      <Route
        path='/'
        element={isLoggedIn()
          ? <AuthenticatedRoutes navigate={navigate} />
          : <Navigate to='/welcome' />
        }
      />

      {/* ====== NO AUTHENTICATION - Sign Up or Login: ======== */}
      <Route
        path='/welcome'
        element={!isLoggedIn()
          ? <LandingPage navigate={navigate} />
          : <Navigate to='/' />
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthenticatedRoutes.js - I use the same layout for each authenticated page, so skip to where it says "MAIN DIV" for the route portion.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSessionTimeOutCheck } from '../../utilities/LoggedInCheck';
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../utilities/LoggedInCheck';
import LoginPopup from '../auth/LoginPopup';
import { findUser } from '../../api_calls/usersAPI';
import HomePage from '../../pages/HomePage';
import ProfilePage from '../../pages/ProfilePage';
import OwnProfilePage from '../../pages/OwnProfilePage';
import MessengerPage from '../../pages/MessengerPage';
import Profile from '../profilepage/Profile';
import OwnProfile from '../profilepage/OwnProfile';
import Navbar from '../navbar/Navbar';
import getSessionUserID from '../../utilities/GetSessionUserID';
import Feed from '../feed/Feed';

const AuthenticatedRoutes = ({ navigate }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
  const sessionUserID = getSessionUserID(token);
  const [sessionUser, setSessionUser] = useState(null);

  // ===== LOGIN POPUP & TIMEOUT CHECKER: COPY TO EVERY AUTHENTICATED PAGE: ==========   
  const showLoginPopup = !useSessionTimeOutCheck(); // checks every 5 seconds if token is valid and changes true/false

  // on component mount: get sessionUserInfo 
  // TODO test:copy to every page, so that it reloads on every new page visit?
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token && sessionUserID) {
      findUser(token, sessionUserID)
      .then(userData => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", userData.token)
        setToken(window.localStorage.getItem("token"))
        setSessionUser(userData.user);
        console.log(userData.user);
      })
    }
  },[])
  
  // =========== JSX FOR COMPONENT =================================== 
  return (
    <div className='h-screen w-screen bg-#bgGrey dark:bg-gray-900 flex flex-col'>

      {/* LOGGED OUT POPUP */}
      {showLoginPopup && 
        <div className='z-40 absolute h-full w-full'>
          <LoginPopup navigate={navigate} />
        </div>
        }

      {/* NAV BAR */}
      <div className='z-30'>
        <Navbar navigate={navigate} token={token} setToken={setToken} 
          sessionUserID={sessionUserID} sessionUser={sessionUser} setSessionUser={sessionUser}/>
      </div>

    {/* MAIN PAGE */}
    <div className='w-screen h-screen flex flex-row '>
    
      {/* MAIN DIV */}
      <div className='w-full h-full'>
        <Routes>
          {/* ------ FEED ------  */}
          <Route path='/'  element={
            <Feed navigate={navigate} token={token} setToken={setToken} 
          sessionUserID={sessionUserID} sessionUser={sessionUser} setSessionUser={sessionUser}/>} />
          
          {/* ------  PROFILE PAGE ------  */}
          <Route path="/users/:userID/"  element={ 
            <Profile navigate={navigate} token={token} setToken={setToken} 
          sessionUserID={sessionUserID} sessionUser={sessionUser} setSessionUser={sessionUser}/>}/>
          {/* ------  SESSION USER'S PROFILE PAGE ------  */}
          <Route path='/profile'  element={ 
            <OwnProfile navigate={navigate} token={token} setToken={setToken} 
          sessionUserID={sessionUserID} sessionUser={sessionUser} setSessionUser={sessionUser}/>}/>

          {/* ------  MESSAGES ------  */}
          {/* <Route path='/messages'  element={ 
            <MessengerPage navigate={navigate} token={token} setToken={setToken} 
            sessionUserID={sessionUserID} sessionUser={sessionUser} setSessionUser={sessionUser}/>}/> */}
        </Routes>
      </div>

      {/* MESSENGER DIV - Online friends */}
      <div className='flex flex-row items-center justify-between h-full sm:w-[28rem]  md:w-[30.5rem] lg:w-[34.5rem] px-4
      border-l-2'>
        MESSENGER
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default AuthenticatedRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route rendered `AuthenticatedRoutes` should specify a wildcard matcher so all descendent routes can also be matched and rendered, e.g. `path="/*"`. This should allows the `Routes` component that `AuthenticatedRoutes` renders to match sub-routes.

See [Splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) for more details.

```
const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <Routes>

      {/* ====== AUTHENTICATION ONLY - Search, Messages, Friends, Notifications : ======== */}
      <Route
        path='/*' // <-- allow sub-route matching
        element={isLoggedIn()
          ? <AuthenticatedRoutes navigate={navigate} />
          : <Navigate to='/welcome' replace />
        }
      />

      {/* ====== NO AUTHENTICATION - Sign Up or Login: ======== */}
      <Route
        path='/welcome'
        element={!isLoggedIn()
          ? <LandingPage navigate={navigate} />
          : <Navigate to='/' replace />
        }
      />

    </Routes>
  );
}
```

For a more conventional route protection implementation see my answer [here](https:///a/66289280/8690857). The basic gist is that `AuthenticatedRoutes` would render an `Outlet` for nested routes to render instead of directly rendering the descendent routes. It leads to cleaner code and separation of concerns.